# Samsung Health SDK Partner Apps program registration

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-health

Currently we are implementing an Android App that uses the step counter from Samsung S Health, BUT Samsung is actually blocking the registration for partner Apps. (bellow screen shot)

[image]

We are now about to release a beta version, so what is the best solution?

1. Release the beta version and ask users to enable developer mode in Samsung S Health App. (When testing using the developer mode of S Health App
2. Wait for Samsung registration
3. Start looking for other alternatives to get step count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone seeing this query after Jan 2021:

As of the latest response from a Samsung Developer Program individual, you can create a support request regarding Partner Program on their portal; please find the official's response here -  https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/partner-program-availability/9899/2